# <img> in JOptionPane and JLabel

Tags: java, html, swing, joptionpane

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html><body><img src=\"pacman.png\"></body></html>");
```

The directory is valid and the html code in my notepad works. Why does the  tag not work in Java components such as JLabel and JOptionPane?

Comment: The img reference needs to generated as a URL

Answer (score 0):

you can use **ImageIcon** to put the image inside the **JOptionPane**

```
    public class Test
        {
            public static void main(String[] args)
            {
 -> //Url link for the image   //ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a1ab0af4997654345d7a949877f8037e?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"));
                final ImageIcon icon = new 

ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\pacemen.jpg");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Blah blah blah", "About", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` is the object that you want to place in the dialog. You're just sending it a String.

HTML works in a JLabel so the following code snippet should work:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel("<html><body><img src=\"pacman.png\"></body></html>"));
```